# Ajax code only working on first <li>

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html-lists

I have the following code:

```
<ul class='app-tasks'>
  <li class='app-tasks__item'>
    <label class='app-tasks__label'>
      <input id='some' value='1' type='checkbox'/>
      <span>One</span>
      <div class='app-tasks__mark'></div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='app-tasks__item'>
    <label class='app-tasks__label'>
      <input id='some' value='2' type='checkbox'/>
      <span>TWO</span>
      <div class='app-tasks__mark'></div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='app-tasks__item'>
    <label class='app-tasks__label'>
      <input id='some' value='3' type='checkbox'/>
      <span>Three</span>
      <div class='app-tasks__mark'></div>
    </label>
  </li>      
</ul>
```

The `li` are being taken from MySQL. The code below is used to delete it.

```
$('#some').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var dataString2 = 'id=' + id;
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "sub.php",
      data: dataString2,
      success: function() {
        console.log("Okay");
        var s = $('.app-tasks .app-tasks__item').length - 1;
        $('.app-header__title').html('All Tasks (' + s + ')');
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

But the code is only being run on the first `li`. There is no problem with the PHP script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id) in HTML must be unique.** Switch to CSS class to identify elements using [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
 <input class="some" value="1" type="checkbox"/>
```

Then use

```
$('.some').change(function() {
  //Rest of the code
});
```

Comment: I would also recommend to use double-quotes than single quote.

Comment: Its a good practice for html markup. Because single quote is only available in html5.

Comment: I find that javascripters seem to use single quotes more often for some reason. I stick with the traditional double quotes though. I didn't in my answer because I copy pasted.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, yea true noticed later. Now corrected

Comment: Oh I see, you were referring to the html.

Comment: @Terminus, I never recommend that approach as duplicate IDs makes your HTML invalid, Test it on W3C validator

Comment: @Terminus, I follow a rule. Never tell invalid/incorrect approach. Its personal choice and its up individuals

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the same id twice. Name each one differently, or use classes instead and do:

```
$('.some').change(function()
{
});
```

Comment: What does your update mean, it shouldn't be part of answer?